# paypal PDT missing variables

Tags: paypal-pdt

I have an issue with PDT.

after payment, when the page returns to the merchant, from paypal, I do the request with the pdt token to get the info on the transaction.

Normally I get these parameters from paypal, in the case of a recurring sale:

```
                [transaction_subject] => paypal product
                [payment_date] => 19:53:02 Jul 12, 2018 PDT
                [txn_type] => subscr_payment
                [subscr_id] => I-XXXXXX
                [last_name] => test
                [residence_country] => CO
                [item_name] => paypal product
                [payment_gross] => 25.00
                [mc_currency] => USD
                [business] => vendor_email
                [payment_type] => instant
                [protection_eligibility] => Ineligible
                [payer_status] => unverified
                [payer_email] => buyer_email
                [txn_id] => XXXXXXXXXXX
                [receiver_email] => vendor_email
                [first_name] => test
                [payer_id] => XXXXXXXX
                [receiver_id] => XXXXXXXX
                [contact_phone] => 55555555
                [item_number] => 1234
                [payment_status] => Completed
                [payment_fee] => 1.64
                [mc_fee] => 1.64
                [mc_gross] => 25.00
                [custom] => 4321
                [charset] => windows-1252
                [] =>
```

but in some of the transactions the response from paypal lacks these 4 items:

subscr_id
item_name
item_number
custom

Any idea why they are missing? the purchases are identical, the only thing different is the buyer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the end, paypal guys said it is a bug from their end. They are trying to fix it in a not foreseeable future :)

It was fixed in the meantime